# How to set gzip in soap xml message

Tags: xml, soap, zip, gzip

I need to set gzip compression on my xml request so the request will be compressed and response will be compressed as well. My XML request is given bellow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tbx="http://aa.bb.net/ota/xsd" xmlns:ota="http://api.bb.net/ota">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <aa:OTA_AuthTokenRQ>
             <aa:AuthTokenType>Request</aa:AuthTokenType>
              <aa:AuthTokenCredentials UserName="TEST" Password="TEST123"/> 
          </aa:OTA_AuthTokenRQ>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Someone please tell me where and how to enable gzip from this request?**

Comment: are you using some kind of framework to send the message (e.g. Axis2) ? If not, you should work at transport level (via HTTP headers if you're using HTTP)

Comment: yes, I am using HTTP. How to put this on HTTP header?

Comment: by setting the "Accept-Encoding" HTTP header to the value"gzip, deflate". Headers set depends on what language you're using. Please note that your web server must be able to actually gzip content (so this may need some tweak on server side to enable gzip compression)